# one to many django add Authors to book

Tags: django, django-models

I have a bookstore, I want to add several Authors to add a new book .how can I do this?my code  just accept one Authors

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Answer (score 1):

You make the relation a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

You can for example create `Book`s and `Author`s, like:

```
sona = Author.objects.create(first_name='Sona', last_name='Charaipotra')
dhon = Author.objects.create(first_name='Dhonielle', last_name='Clayton')

book1 = Book.objects.create(title='Tiny Pretty Things', topic='dance')
book1.authors.add(sona, dhon)
```

> **Note**: models typically have a *singular* name, so `Author`, instead of <s>`Authors`</s>.